# Matching Xcode project bundle identifier with code signing identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

I have a project that runs fine in the simulator. When I attempt to run on a device I get the following alert:

**App installation failed**

```
This application’s bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier.
```

I tried the various suggestions from posts uncovered by searching on the above message text. All to no avail.

Question: How do I reveal the values that aren't matching? I know what value I'm using for the Bundle Identifier. How do I reveal the value for the Code Signing Identifier? (I know the Code Signing Identity). Exactly what values is Xcode attempting to match and how are they established?

A bit more info:

I'm using Xcode's **Automatically managing signing** setting. I've set the Team. The info disclosure button next to **Xcode Managed Profile** reveals a popover with six entrees, all which appear OK, including the first entry that the App ID matches the Bundle ID.

I've also tried various manual attempts.

### UPDATE

I attempted a "*start from scratch*" process as outlined here:

**Phase 1 - Cleanup**

Xcode:

- Remove all provisioning profiles from device
- Clean project
- Close project
- Quit Xcode

KeyChain:

- Remove iPhone Developer certificate
- Do not remove any login keys since there are many keys with the same name and I can't distiguish between them

Apple Dev site:

- Remove all iOS Certificates
- Remove all Development profiles
- Do not remove any devices

MBP:

- Remove all provisioning profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
- Remove all project dirs from /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Reboot

**Phase 2 - Build Project**

Xcode:

- Launch and open project
- General->Signing->Status reports:
  `Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain. To create a new one, you must first revoke the existing certificate.`
- Click Revoke button.

  - Certificate is auto-generated
- Build (success)
- Inspect build log to verify the SHA1 used for codesigning steps matches Keychain SHA1 of auto-generated certificate

KeyChain:

- Verify that auto-generated certificate exists in KeyChain

MBP:

- Verify an auto-generated provisioning profile has been added to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
- Verify device UUID is include in auto-generated provisioning profile

Apple Dev site:

- Verify auto-generated iOS Development certificate exists
- The auto-generated provisioning profile is not listed (no profiles exists)

**Phase 3 - Run Project**

Xcode:

- Run in simulator (success)
- Run on device

  **App installation failed**

  `This application’s bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check is your project bundle id's matching in

- General Tab
- Info.plist([screenshot for inf.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdCBo.png))
- Build settings tab([screenshot for build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxeBX.png).)

That might be an issue.

Let me know if it's helps.

Comment: I use $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) in the info.plist to ensure the two are the same.

Comment: Is your device UDID registered in developer account, which you use as team ?
Also maybe your device is registered in dev account but not  included in provisioning profile for signing ?

Comment: I've tried on two separate devices and have verified that each is in the ProvisionedDevices array in the embedded.mobileprovision file of the built application.

Comment: 1. Do you have signing certificate installed on your Keychain ?
2. Did you try to do so Xcode/Preference/Accounts/ select development team and "Download All Profiles" ?

Comment: 1, Yes. I've even checked that the SHA1 of the cert being used for signing matches that in my KeyChain.  2. Yes, I had do this step as well.

Comment: Not the solution for you but have you tried to change bundle id in General tab and try to run on that device if it's work most probably issue is in provisioning profile that Xcode automatically choose.

Comment: I've tried a number of changes to the Bundle ID to mark the effect. Same result in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was trying to package a cross-compiled dylib as a framework. Looking into the device log I was able to get a more detailed description

```
codeSigningInfoByValidatingResources:performingOnlineAuthorization:ignoringCachedSigningInfo:checkingTrustCacheIfApplicable:error:]: 817: Code signing identifier (DYLIB_NAME) does not match bundle identifier (BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
```

My solution was to adjust the DYLIB_NAME to match the BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER. However, there was a catch: Somehow, XCode seems to be able to extract the original build-name of the dylib. Simply renaming the file thus did not help: I had to adjust the build-target of the dylib to make this solution work.

Answer (score 0):

in iTunes they changed it to have a flag for each role if he will have Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. and by default its false.

All i had to do is to:

go to iTunesConnect -> Users and Access -> edit my role by checking the box of "Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"

[image]